# Splash screen changes each run (XCODE, PhoneGAP)

Tags: xcode, cordova, splash-screen

I'm having the most weird problem I had for long time.

I'm using PhoneGap with XCODE 4.3.2 I have use the XCODE GUI Option to select 2 versions of the splash screen (retina and non-retina).

When running it on the device, it shows my splash screen, the next time i run it changed to the default splash that comes with the phonegap.

the weird thing is its changes each time i'm running the application on my device (XCODE Schema --> Run )

Any idea'a what can cause this weird behavior?

Answer (score 1):

It also happened with me. And I resolved it by replacing the default phonegap splash screens with mine. It worked fine.